# Is there a better solution to rounded corners in UITableview cell than this one?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to give each cell spacing on each side by 5 and then make the corners rounded.

I have this so far:

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 100.0;
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        var whiteRoundedView : UIView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 10, self.view.frame.size.width, 70))
        whiteRoundedView.layer.backgroundColor = CGColorCreate(CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0])
        whiteRoundedView.layer.masksToBounds = false
        whiteRoundedView.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0
        whiteRoundedView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(-1, 1)
        whiteRoundedView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
        cell.contentView.addSubview(whiteRoundedView)
        cell.contentView.sendSubviewToBack(whiteRoundedView)
    }
```

This will make each cell have a width of 100% which I dont want to since I want space on the sides as well.

It also feels a bit laggy when scrolling through a long list.

So is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little trick: Customize your tableview cell, add a main view to your cell's contentview, you set margins and corner radius to this main view, say you want a spacing by 6 between two cells, then you set your main view 3 points margins to cell's contentview both top and bottom

Comment: Cool, so more or less, place a uiview inside each cell and style that uiview? But how do I remove the cell lines/insets? And is it possible to add spacing between each cell in storyboard? I will accept your answer as soon it lets me

Comment: self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None did it

Comment: Yep. And there is no direct way to set spacing between cells in Nib or programmatically, but you  do can layout views inside a cell as what I said to make it like they have a spacing between each other.